# Trying to find a power/feat, free stealth check at start of combat if you have concealment?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers

I've been trying a bunch of different things trying to come up with a ranged attacker that I like. Right now I'm working with a Shadowy Rogue.

Some time ago I remember bumping into a power or feat or something that granted a free Stealth check when you roll initiative if you have cover or concealment, which I have with my Enshrouding Candle. I know I saw the Gnome racial ability but I think I saw something else that does the same thing too and didn't require a race. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking of the Bregan D'aerthe Spy theme's Utility 2 power that reads:

> Free Action      Personal
>
> Trigger: You have any cover or concealment when you roll initiative.
>
> Effect: You can make a Stealth check to hide.

It can be accessed by taking the Bregan D'aerthe Spy theme and then taking this power as your utility 2 power.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to wax eagle's answer, one of the races has this ability naturally. I think it is gnome, but I would have to break out my 4e books again to verify which one for sure, as I haven't played in about a year.